# Firebase Authentication - Password Encryption necessary?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using the Firebase Authentication and my question is: Do i need to Encrypt the password when the Client sends it to Firebase? Or when he Signs up in my App? Some say, i dont need to because Firebase does it already and others say "of course you need to". Please Help me, what are you thinking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Firebase Authentication, then you can send a plain password and Firebase will encrypt it. You don't have to encrypt the password.